# redirecting http to https (only admin panel not frontend )

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I installed `SSL` for `wordpress` but `https` only show up `admin panel`, i want to show it on all frontend pages i have add `.htaccess` file in root directory but not done.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase / 

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Show you `.htaccess` please.

Comment: Consider adding content of `.htaccess` in question description.

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
`RewriteEngine On`

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

in wp-config.php define this

```
<?php  define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); ?>
```

Comment: yes!  Only need to change your address url in wordpress general->setting replace http with https.

Comment: my admin site is working with `https` but frontend is redirected to http

Comment: For me It's working after changing http to https in general setting. please check your SSL Certificate Setting.